# SVN Commit frequently Fail Internal Error 500

Tags: apache, svn

## Hello everyone,

Commit on svn is becoming strange : it fails with this error

> Error: Commit failed (details follow): Error: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to Error: POST request for '/svn/repo/!svn/me'

And after many attempts it works.

## These are some lines of the log :

```
[Mon Jan 09 11:44:14 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
[Mon Jan 09 11:44:14 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #106]
[Mon Jan 09 11:44:14 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Error writing base64 data: Unknown error  [500, #106]
[Mon Jan 09 11:19:25 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Could not MERGE resource "/svn/repo/!svn/txn/101403-26c0" into "/svn/repo/branches/PATH/resources".  [409, #0]
[Mon Jan 09 11:19:25 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Could not fetch resource information.  [404, #0]
[Mon Jan 09 11:19:25 2017] [error] [client X.X.X.X] Named transaction doesn't exist.  [404, #0]
```

## And my httpd.conf part of SVN Conf

```
RedirectMatch ^(/svn)$ $1/
<Location /svn/>   
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath "C:/svn-repos"
   SVNReposName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthzSVNAccessFile "C:\servers\csvn\data/conf/svn_access_file"
  SVNListParentPath On
  AuthzForceUsernameCase Lower
  Allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "CollabNet Subversion Repository"
  AuthBasicProvider  ldap-users

  <LimitExcept OPTIONS GET PROPFIND REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

The commit fail is becoming frequent and embarassing so please any help will be appreciated.

Thx in advance.

PS : I'm using Subversion Edge 3.3.0-3490.106 and Subversion 1.7.9-3490.106

Answer (score 0):

1. You use an outdated and unsupported version of SVN. You should plan upgrading your server and clients.
2. If you have an antivirus on the server or client, make sure that it does not touch your server and repositories. There is a great chance that a malfunctioning antivirus is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Check SELinux:

SELinux is preventing `/usr/sbin/httpd` from name_connect access on the tcp_socket port 389.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```